# How to use NSSortDescriptor with nested relationships several levels down

Tags: swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

Can I sort with NSSortDescriptor several levels down using relationship1.relationship2.attribute?

all relationships are many-to-one

Lets say that current "component" has a relationship "part" (to one), and "part" has it's relationship "typeANDVariant" (to one)

I get runtime error when executing fetch with the following searchDescriptor:

```
let searchDescriptor=NSSortDescriptor(key: "part.typeANDVariant.actVariantName", ascending:true)
```

actVariantName being a string

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath part.typeANDVariant.actVariantName not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Component id=7>'
```

If I don't sort, I am able to access part.typeANDVariant.actVariantName without a problem and display the relevant data (string)

The following works also:

```
let searchDescriptor=NSSortDescriptor(key: "part.partDescription", ascending:true)
```

partDescription being an attribute (string)

To me it seems as if I cannot use NSSortDescriptor with nested relationships.

[image: Data model]

Comment: Try `typeANDvariant` instead of `typeANDVariant` (lower case v).

Comment: thanks a lot. I feel a bit stupid for not seeing this :)

Answer (score 0):

answered by Willeke:
Try typeANDvariant instead of typeANDVariant (lower case v). – Willeke

thanks.